# Converting char into NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am having trouble converting arguments to NSString format for my Cocoa application. I start my application like so:

```
open my.app --args a1 a2
```

I try to access the arguments like so:

```
const char *h_path_char = [[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:1] fileSystemRepresentation];
const char *s_path_char = [[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:2] fileSystemRepresentation];

NSString *h_path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:h_path_char];
NSString *s_path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s_path_char];

NSLog(@"%s", h_path);
NSLog(@"%s", s_path);
```

However, Xcode complains about the `NSLog` with the following warning:

> Conversion specifies type "char" but the argument has type "NSString".

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `NSLog(@"%@", h_path);`?

Comment: @Robert, yes, or print the original `const char *` with `%s`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`%s` is meant for C strings. You should use `%@` instead of `%s` to output `NSString` (and other Foundation types) to `NSLog`.

Comment: Thanks ayoy - I made a rookie mistake.